# Force Visual Studio to update Android Resources in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I've been having a problem with Visual Studio 2019 (and before it Visual Studio 2017) Xamarin.Android in which every time I add a view with an ID to an .axml layout file it doesn't generate the IDs into `Resource.Id`. The only solution I've had is to go to the project's folder, delete both `bin` and `obj` folder and then rebuilding the solution. Not even a clean-rebuild solves this, I always have to delete both folders to force Visual Studio to generate the IDs.

Is there any CLI command I can use to force Visual Studio to actually update the IDs from all layouts? This bug has been around (at least for me) for a long time.

Comment: There is a offical article about this issue, you could refer to it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/resource-designer-wont-update

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT this does not work. The guide is from 2017, my project was created in november 2018, so it's not an "old project dealing with new APIs". Still, I created a fresh project and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem...workaround here is

every time you update your "activity_main.axml" file , make sure you hit keyboard "Ctrl +S " which will save the axml file changes....then when you switch back your cs file and try intellisense again , you shall see the newly added or rename view IDs

[image] just like this picture show

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.11 , can you try update your version and try above workaround and see does it work on your ends ? ops , forget about it , you are using 2019